# Custom progress bar inside a status strip. c#

Tags: c#, forms, progress-bar, statusstrip

Hi All and good morning.

I am currently working on a text based RPG using windows forms.

How would i go about creating a custom progress bar on a status strip?

Thanks

Lucas

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything so far? Show your effort first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: Sorry, my design skills arent great, i'm more of a back end programmer. IF someone could give me a hint on how to go about doing it, Ill give it a shot then ask again. Thanks